# execute script when a hardware is plugged in

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, ubuntu-10.04, automation

**How can I tell my Ubuntu installation to execute some scripts when I connect a specific hardware?**

For example: I have an external eSATA disk. When this (and only this) disk is plugged in, my notebook should execute the backup.sh script.

Additionally it would be nice if I get informed about those automatic executions. The most beautiful thing would be an indicator in my gnome panel. But a terminal that pops up and shows the output of the script would also be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to tell udev to execute something when the device
is plugged in. Here http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2009/09/25/automatic-backups-with-udev/
you see how someone else has done it with a usb disk, doing it with a
e-sata disk should be very similar.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to have the script running as a user daemon, listening for hal events over D-Bus.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RUN in a udev rule to accomplish at least part of this. See for example this howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsbDriveDoSomethingHowto

That doesn't cover notification or output -- you could have the script put its results in a file, and have something else running in your account monitor that file. (There's a number of existing programs made to monitor files in a GUI -- there's a gkrellm plugin, for example.)

The suggestion of making a background process listening to dbus events is another promising approach, and is in some ways more elegant (not the least being that you don't need to mess with system-wide configuration). But it also requires a little more linux-plumbing-level knowledge and programming work.